# jquery script tags conflict

Tags: jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I use multiple versions of jQuery on the same page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1566595/can-i-use-multiple-versions-of-jquery-on-the-same-page)

Iam using 3 JQUery wordpress plugins, so in my header.php file, I have 3 similar jquery scripts (which are very important inorder to make my plugin work..) and besides iam facing a problem if one removed/added..

here they are: (in my header.php)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="liquidcarousel/js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

 <script src="http://mywebsite.com/price-filter-wid-css/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
```

these 3 are conflicting each other and output not getting properly.. So, how can I make my plugins work..?

So, do I need to keep like this as below:

```
<script>
var jq142 = jQuery.noConflict();
</script>
<script>
var jq142 = jQuery.noConflict();
</script>
<script>
var jq182 = jQuery.noConflict();
</script>
```

**Anything wrong from above???**

**Here are my other codes:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $('#liquid1').liquidcarousel({height:129, duration:100, hidearrows:false});
        });


$(function() {
        $( "#makeup" ).slider({
            range: true,
            min: 0,
            max: 500,
            values: [ 0, 500 ],
            slide: function( event, ui ) {
            $( "#minprice" ).val( ui.values[ 0 ] );     
            $( "#maxprice" ).val( ui.values[1 ] );  
            $( "#pricego" ).val( ui.values[0]+'-'+ui.values[1] );
        }

        });

    });
```

**So, how can I correctly use above functions so that to avoid from these jquery conflictions..?**

As per you said, I have changed as below:

```
$(function() {
        mywebsite( "#makeup" ).slider({
            range: true,
            min: 0,
            max: 500,
            values: [ 0, 500 ],
            slide: function( event, ui ) {
            $( "#minprice" ).val( ui.values[ 0 ] );     
            $( "#maxprice" ).val( ui.values[1 ] );  
            $( "#pricego" ).val( ui.values[0]+'-'+ui.values[1] );
        }

        });

    });


$(document).ready(function() {
            liquidcarousel('#liquid1').liquidcarousel({height:129, duration:100, hidearrows:false});
        });
```

**PLease kindly correct me , if Iam wrong somwehere...**

**After doing all changes, this is my code: (but still not getting output)**

```
<!-- Liquidcarousel Stuff  -->
<link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href='liquidcarousel/css/style.css' />
<link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href='liquidcarousel/css/liquidcarousel.css' />
<script type="text/javascript" src="liquidcarousel/js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
     var liquidcarousel = $.noConflict(true);
     </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="liquidcarousel/js/jquery.liquidcarousel.pack.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function() {
            liquidcarousel('#liquid1').liquidcarousel({height:129, duration:100, hidearrows:false});
        });

        $(document).ready(function() {
            liquidcarousel('#liquid2').liquidcarousel({height:129, duration:100, hidearrows:false});
        });

</script>



<!-- Categories Display Widget Stuff   -->
<link href="http://mywebsite.com/cat-wid-css/css/dcaccordion.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="http://mywebsite.com/cat-wid-css/css/skins/blue.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="http://mywebsite.com/cat-wid-css/css/skins/graphite.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="http://mywebsite.com/cat-wid-css/css/skins/grey.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
       var googleapis = $.noConflict(true);
     </script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://mywebsite.com/cat-wid-css/js/jquery.cookie.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://mywebsite.com/cat-wid-css/js/jquery.hoverIntent.minified.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://mywebsite.com/cat-wid-css/js/jquery.dcjqaccordion.2.7.min.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function($){

                    googleapis('.accordion-6').dcAccordion({
                        eventType: 'hover',
                        autoClose: true,
                        saveState: true,
                        disableLink: true,
                        menuClose: false,
                        speed: 'medium',
                        showCount: true,

                        autoExpand: true,
                        cookie  : 'dcjq-accordion-1',
                        classExpand  : 'dcjq-current-parent',

                        menuClose: false    
                    });

});
</script>







<!-- Price Filter Display Widget Stuff   -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://mywebsite.com/price-filter-wid-css/themes/base/jquery.ui.all.css">
    <script src="http://mywebsite.com/price-filter-wid-css/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript">
           var mywebsite = $.noConflict(true);
       </script>
    <script src="http://mywebsite.com/price-filter-wid-css/ui/jquery.ui.core.js"></script>
    <script src="http://mywebsite.com/price-filter-wid-css/ui/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
    <script src="http://mywebsite.com/price-filter-wid-css/ui/jquery.ui.mouse.js"></script>
    <script src="http://mywebsite.com/price-filter-wid-css/ui/jquery.ui.slider.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://mywebsite.com/price-filter-wid-css/demos.css">
    <style>
    #demo-frame > div.demo { padding: 10px !important; };
    </style>

    <script>


    mywebsite(function() {
        mywebsite( "#makeup" ).slider({
            range: true,
            min: 0,
            max: 500,
            values: [ 0, 500 ],
            slide: function( event, ui ) {
            mywebsite( "#minprice" ).val( ui.values[ 0 ] );     
            mywebsite( "#maxprice" ).val( ui.values[1 ] );  
            mywebsite( "#pricego" ).val( ui.values[0]+'-'+ui.values[1] );
        }

        });

    });





    </script>
```

**Iam still not getting output .. pls tell me still what went wrong..?...**

Comment: Are you _really_ including the same version of jQuery twice? ಠ_ಠ

Comment: I really didnt get with those links... Now what I have to do actually...? pls suggest me...

Comment: Hey pls check my answer once above, is that correct..?

Answer (score 0):

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="liquidcarousel/js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript">
     var someName = $.noConflict(true);
     </script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript">
       var googleapis = $.noConflict(true);
     </script>

   <script src="http://mywebsite.com/price-filter-wid-css/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript">
           var mywebsite = $.noConflict(true);
       </script>
```

Then, instead of `$('#selector').function();`, you'd do `someName('#selector').function();` or `googleapis('#selector').function();` or `mywebsite('#selector').function();` to avoid confliction.

Instead of `$` have to use `someName` or `googleapis` or `mywebsite` whatever you need

```
$(document).ready(function() {
           // $('#liquid1').liquidcarousel({height:129, duration:100, hidearrows:false});
            googleapis('#liquid1').liquidcarousel({height:129, duration:100, hidearrows:false}); //if you need to use googleapis jquery version in that case
        });


someName(function() {
        someName( "#makeup" ).slider({ // if you need liquidcarousel to use in this case
            range: true,
            min: 0,
            max: 500,
            values: [ 0, 500 ],
            slide: function( event, ui ) {
            someName( "#minprice" ).val( ui.values[ 0 ] );     
            someName( "#maxprice" ).val( ui.values[1 ] );  
            someName( "#pricego" ).val( ui.values[0]+'-'+ui.values[1] );
        }

        });

    });
```

Comment: I edited above, could you please check..?

Comment: PLease check my final code above (after doing full editing), pls tell me whats wrong above?

Comment: var liquidcarousel = $.noConflict(true); 
Use var someName = $.noConflict(true); instead and make correction in all place.Hope it helps !

If still problems, see http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/ to get clear conception

Comment: var liquidcarousel = $.noConflict(true); Use var liquidcarousel = $.noConflict(true); instead, 

What U changed?

Comment: Previous comment is Edited !! Now see

Comment: I already have unique named variables..Dont know whats wrong in above code..